# x509 extensions: can the "extnValue" be empty?

Tags: ssl-certificate, x509

I'm writing a script that parses x509 certificates. x509 v3 certificates have extensions which are an ASN.1 sequence containing an OID, a `critical` flag, and an octetString called `extnValue`.

For the `basicConstraints` extension, the extnValue is supposed to be another ASN.1 sequence with the details.

I've encountered a certificate that had an empty sequence there instead. Literally the bytes `0x30 0x00` which parse to an ASN.1 sequence of zero length, instead of the expected set of data (boolean for certificate authority and an integer for path length.

The fact that I found a cert in the wild with this quality implies that it **is** valid, but I was hoping to find a concrete protocol rule about this so my script can handle it correctly instead of throwing an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`extnValue` isn't empty, it's `30 00`, which is an empty sequence.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.9 says that the encoding of a Basic Constraints extension value is

```
BasicConstraints ::= SEQUENCE {
    cA                      BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
    pathLenConstraint       INTEGER (0..MAX) OPTIONAL }
```

The empty sequence is therefore logically `{ cA: FALSE, pathLenConstraint: Not Present }`.

Because certificates use ASN.1 DER encoding, a `DEFAULT` value should never be specified, and the text says that `pathLenConstraint` should never be specified when `cA` is set to `FALSE`, so `30 00` is the only valid form for "this certificate does not represent a Certificate Authority".

Comment: Great thank you! Answer is very simple.